# Create page of blocks only / Create a node of blocks

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

Sometimes I use a basic page as a place holder for the purpose of creating a node to hold blocks.

So I create a basic page and link it to a menu, then I use the blocks interface to configure certain blocks to display on that page only.

The problem with this approach is twofold.  Firstly I don't *need* the page, but secondly when a user tries to edit the page they're understandably surprised to find nothing.

Is there a better way of creating a node of blocks?  Ideally, the more lightweight the better..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this solution requires installing another module, but also provides other great functionality such as revisions.

http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock

You would also have to convert all of your old blocks into these new "Node Blocks"

Another option would be

http://drupal.org/project/empty_page